# How do i autogenerate an ID in a form?

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>The test</title>
</head>
<BODY>
<?php
require 'DBConn.php';
$db = @odbc_connect ($dbconn, '', '');

if (array_key_exists('ID', $_POST)) {
$sql = "insert into Landlords (ID, Landlord, Address, Contact) values 
('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[land]', '$_POST[add]', '$_POST[con]')";

print '<h2>Landlord ' .$_POST['ID'] .' added</h2>';
print '<p>Return at <a href=admin.htm>Admin Page</a>';
odbc_exec ($db, $sql);
} else {
?>
<form action="addLandlord.php" method="post">
<p>Create a new Landlord ID:<br><input type="text" name="ID" size="30">
<p>Enter the Landlord's Name:<br><input type="text" name="land" size="30">
<p>Enter the Landlord's Address:<br><textarea name="con" cols="50" rows="10"
</textarea>
<p>Enter the Landlord's Contact Details:<br><textarea name="con" cols="50" rows="10">
</textarea>
<p>and click here
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, firstly when using this code you have to create an ID - I need help in autogenerating these values and entering them into the database. The database automatically generates them, but I don't know how to change the php to accomodate this.

Secondly, how do I add a "you entered the wrong values they must be so and so" to pop up when entering the wrong values?

Thanks guys!

Comment: If the database generates the ID, why do you need the user to enter one?  (Hint: If the user enters one, the database isn't generating it.  The two scenarios are mutually-exclusive.)  For adding validation, all you need to do is check the values in your PHP code to see if they're "valid" (however you define that).  If they're not, display an error.  If they are, continue adding them to the database.

Answer (score 1):

If your database table has an id column that is set to auto increment, you don't want to try and set that value.  That's what auto increment does: It creates an id automatically that is unique.  Moreover, if your database isn't set to auto increment the id, change it.  It's just a terrible idea to ask a user to create an ID.  Forget about the fact that it would require a lot of unnecessary code to try and make sure it was unique and potentially frustrating back and forth with the user. ick!

1. Delete the input for id in your html.
2. Remove the array_key_exists if statement, you can check if values are set with isset btw.
3. Set your POST values in variables (if you don't you'll need to add quotes on the $_POST["value"] array key and you need to then escape the quotes in your statement OR you have to enclose each in curly braces), then change your sql statement to something like this:

   $sql = "insert into Landlords (Landlord, Address, Contact) values 
   ($landlord, $add, $con)";

The database will handle the id with the auto increment by virtue of creating the new record.

For validation, you need to search for tutorials.  There are tons of them for PHP.

**EDIT:**
Here's a sample page with some checking to make sure the values aren't empty.  That's all it does.  As I said there are many many tutorials for validation and you should use a tutorial to learn the many ways that can be accomplished.

Also, you don't say what kind of database you're connecting to, so I'm just guessing that your connection string and sql statement are correct.  Further, this assumes that your database ID column is indeed set to autogenerate and id with (auto increment or identity or whatever your database supports).

There are comments in the code to provide some hints about what's going on, but it should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>The test</title>
<style> 
.error { color: red; };
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require 'DBConn.php';
$db = @odbc_connect ($dbconn, '', '');
$display = "form";
$landlord = "";
$landlorderror = "";
$address = "";
$addresserror = "";
$contact = "";
$contacterror = "";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if (empty($_POST["landlord"])) {
     $landlorderror = "Landlord name is required";
   } else {
     $landlord = cleanup($_POST["landlord"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addresserror = "Address is required";
   } else {
     $address = cleanup($_POST["address"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["contact"])) {
     $contacterror = "Contact info is required";
   } else {
     $contact = cleanup($_POST["contact"]);
   }
    if ($landlorderror === "" && $addresserror === ""  && $contacterror === "") {
        $sql = "insert into Landlords (Landlord, Address, Contact) values ('$landlord', '$address', '$contact')";
        odbc_exec ($db, $sql);
        //not sure what DB you're connecting to, if it supports odbc_num_rows() 
        //you can check here if the insert resulted in a record being created
        //by checking if it returns 1 and setting the $display value inside the if statement
        $display = "successmsg";
    }
}

//this does a little sanitizing but if you can use PDO, that would be better
function cleanup($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);  //b/c you're displaying the data back in the same form
   return $data;
}

//So, this is just going to display the success message if the display variable has been set to something other than form.
//That only happens if there were no empty fields and the db insert was run
if ($display != 'form') { 
    print '<h2>Landlord ' .$landlord .' added</h2>';
    print '<p>Return at <a href=admin.htm>Admin Page</a>';
} else {
//The form action is set to itself and each of the input values is set to the value that was entered
//if the form was already attempted to be submitted.  If an error exists, it will be displayed after the input label.
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<p>Enter the Landlord's Name:<span class="error">* <?php echo $landlorderror;?></span><br><input type="text" name="landlord" size="30"  value="<?php echo $landlord;?>">
<p>Enter the Landlord's Address:<span class="error">* <?php echo $addresserror;?></span><br><textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="10"><?php echo $address;?>
</textarea>
<p>Enter the Landlord's Contact Details:<span class="error">* <?php echo $contacterror;?></span><br><textarea name="contact" cols="50" rows="10"><?php echo $contact;?>
</textarea>
<p>and click here
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, sorry I am very new at this.. if i delete the array key then the page seems to break could you edit the above code to show what you mean please?

Comment: What I mean is that since you're not going to have an id in your post array any more, you can't use that as your check.  An alternative would be to use: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'), which will just check if the form is being posted.  I'll update my answer with a more complete code example later.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am having an issue with a similar page now as well.. i copied the code over and edited relative to the other page but I dont know why it doesn't work like this one?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

and then echo it like this in your input field:

```
echo generateRandomString();
```